# Integrating CKEditor in an ASP.Net Webforms Application

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, webforms, ckeditor

I'm trying to use CKEditor in my Webforms application and I have tried many other methods without success. Can someone help? The site uses a Site.Master file which all the aspx files provide content for using content place-holders. So I place the JavaScript call in the ASPX rather than in the master file.

I'm also trying to get it to edit in a content editable div element. It works fine in a small test site but not in my application. Any ideas?

My Site.master has two content placeholders I want to use:

`<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Scripts" runat="server" />`
and
`<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">`

An then my aspx files have:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="Scripts" runat="server"> 
<script src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script> 
</asp:Content>`
```

and

`<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <div id="renderTarget" renderwidth="1100">
</asp:Content>
</asp:Content>`

Somewhere in my JavaScript, I set the content editable of my renderTarget div to true.

`$(".contentbox[dynamic='true']").attr("contenteditable", "true");`

And at this point, I expect CKedtor to add its controls to the div. But It doesn't. i use the same process with TinyMCE  and it works fine.

Comment: We can't really determine what's causing it to fail without *any* code that demonstrates the problem.  Can you show the relevant code and explain in what way it fails?

Comment: Site.Master? ASPX files? ContentPlaceHolders? Are you sure you have an MVC project?

Comment: Yes its MVC: My Site.master loads a bunch of scripts and then puts this place-holder:

'code' 
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Scripts" runat="server" />
'code' 

So in my view, which is a dashboard that can be edited, i have: 

'code'
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="Scripts" runat="server">
      <link href="/CSS/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css" rel="stylesheet"type="text/css" />
<script src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
</asp:Content>

Comment: @jyoansah that is not MVC. That is Webforms.

Comment: OK, So I'm obviously a rookie at this. How would I use CKEdior in webforms then, because I managed to use TinyMCE by doing the same thing but CKEditor does not show up.

Comment: @jyoansah without seeing any code, there is no way to tell or help.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev Ok, Edited to show some  of the code I'm using. Hopefully this explains the problem better

Comment: You list `ckeditor/ckeditor.js` as the path to the javascript files.  Are you sure that is valid?  Are your .aspx files in a sub directory?  If so then you need to change the path to the .js file to where it actually is.  In other words, use a root relative path like `/ckeditor/ckeditor.js`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have CKEditor in your project correctly, it is as simple as:

```
<textarea cols="80" class="ckeditor" id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="10"></textarea>
```

or even

```
<div contenteditable="true">...</div>
```

Also, you may want to read up on [jQuery Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

An example more like what you posted:

```
<div id="ckMe">...</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ckMe").attr("contenteditable", "true");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I'm trying to use a content editable div element not a text area.

Comment: So CKEditor is supposed to automatically pick up the ckMe div when you set its content-editable div to true. However, it doesn't and clicking the div just allows text editing capabilities. the CKeditor tools are not show.

Comment: @jyoansah then you are likely getting javascript errors because you don't have all the folders and scripts necessary to make ckeditor work. Make sure you are using all the items provided in the download, and like Chris Lively said, ensure your reference is correct.

Comment: I think you're right. I created a test page and managed to get it to work on that test page. So it likely has something to do with the particular page I'm trying to load it on and the links I'm using. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

all you need is to install the version for asp.net in your project and then just use it as simple as adding a usercontrol:

```
<ckeditor:ckeditorcontrol ID="CkEditor1" runat="server"></ckeditor:ckeditorcontrol>
```

[Documentation from ckEditor](https://ckeditor.com/blog/CKEditor-for-ASP.NET-Released/)